# How to make transaction SQL queries explicitly in Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

Just like this

```
SET autocommit=0;
BEGIN;
...
```

But I found that in Spring(or JDBC) transaction queries not have `BEGIN`;

How to make SQL query start transaction explicitly in Spring framework transaction?

```
SET autocommit=0;
BEGIN;
...
```

The reason why I want to start transaction explicitly is I'm using ProxySQL as database proxy service. But there are some problems not friendly support to implicity transaction https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=5997899

Comment: The Spring way is to annotate the method with `@Transactional`. As an aside, if you're using JDBC directly, then the proper way is to use `connection.setAutoCommit(false)`, the driver will then automatically start a transaction when it needs to, and you would then commit with `connection.commit()`. You should not use this type of statements (e.g. `BEGIN`) to configure transactional behaviour as it may result in incorrect behaviour because the driver may not track those statements and still think it is in auto-commit mode.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I'm using `@Transactional` and `TransactionTemplate`, but I want to start transaction explicitly. Because I use ProxySQL as database proxy who not support implicit transaction, You can see detail reason here: https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=5997899

Comment: That is pertinent information which you should include in your question itself. Also, implicit transaction start is something JDBC requires of a driver, but a driver implementation can send an explicit transaction start, so one does not preclude the other.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks a lot, I re-edit this question. But I wonder how to send an explicit transaction start In Spring transaction? Could you plz give me some information or demo code?

Comment: Formally, you can't, because neither JDBC, and by extension, Spring support explicit transaction starts. If the JDBC driver you use doesn't itself send explicit transaction starts when it needs to, you will need to find or write one that does.

Answer (score 0):

I read up on this on baeldung recently, I think your exact answer is provided here ->
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactions-read-only#2-jpaspring

You can either let Spring take over the transaction handling with the `@Transactional` annotation, or use the annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories(enableDefaultTransactions = false)` if you want to manually decide where Transactions should be handeled.